# How to configure AWS.Logger.SeriLog in App.config

Tags: c#, amazon-cloudwatch, serilog, .net-4.8

I'm trying to convert this AWS.Logger.SeriLog configuration example from json to xml and struggling to find examples and the correct naming convention conversions.

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "AWS.Logger.SeriLog" ],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Override": {
    "System": "Warning",
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting": "Warning"
  }
},
"Enrich": [ "WithMachineName", "FromLogContext", "WithExceptionDetails", "WithAssemblyInformationalVersion" ],
"Region": "us-east-1",
"LogGroup": "MyLogGroup",
"LibraryLogFileName": "Logs/serilog-aws-errors.txt",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "AWSSeriLog",
    "Args": {
      "textFormatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
    }
  }
]
```

}

This is what I've come up with so far in xml

```
<appSettings>

    <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Information" />
    <add key="serilog:minimum-level:override:Microsoft" value="Warning" />

    <add key="serilog:region" value="us-east-1" />
    <add key="serilog:log-group" value="MyLogGroup" />
    <add key="serilog:library-log-file-name" value="Logs/serilog-aws-errors.txt" />

    <add key="serilog:using:AWSSeriLog" value="AWS.Logger.SeriLog" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:AWSSeriLog.textFormatter" value="Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog" />
    
    <add key="serilog:enrich:WithMachineName" />
    <add key="serilog:enrich:FromLogContext" />
    <add key="serilog:enrich:WithExceptionDetails" />
    <add key="serilog:enrich:WithAssemblyInformationalVersion" />
</appSettings>
```

This key is causing an exception when the configuration is read:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:AWSSeriLog.textFormatter" value="Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog" />
```

Comment: Is there a reason you'd prefer XML over JSON?

Comment: This is for a .NET framework WinForms application and I did not know it was an option to use an appsettings.json file from that type of application. If it is I have lots of other config settings I'd like to avoid having to convert to JSON.

Comment: Ah makes sense, might be worthwhile pointing that out :)

Comment: Check this sample [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/tree/master/samples/Serilog/SerilogTestCodeFromConfig) - I know it uses .NET Core 2.2 but it should be on the same .NET standard, set the project to .NET Framework 4.8 and see if it perhaps works?

Comment: I think it should, I'd try it myself but on phone so let me know, sorry I can't write a full researched answer yet :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to add the configuration below to the appsettins.json file but here you are:

```
//...

using Amazon.Runtime;
using AWS.Logger;
using AWS.Logger.SeriLog;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Context;
using Serilog.Formatting.Json;

// ...

// create a config object from the appsettings.json file
private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; } = new 
    ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

// ...

// you can get these configs from your appsettings.json
var awsS3sKey = Configuration["aws:access.key"];
var awsS3Secret = Configuration["aws:secret.key"];
var logGroupName = Configuration["aws:log.group.name"];
var region = Configuration["aws:log.region"];

// create your AWS credential
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsS3sKey, awsS3Secret);

// create a logger for AWS Cloudwatch
var awsConfiguration = new AWSLoggerConfig
{
    Region = region,
    LogGroup = logGroupName,
    Credentials = credentials
};

// create a serilog config
var config = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
    .WriteTo.AWSSeriLog(awsConfiguration, null, new JsonFormatter());

// logger is ready
Log.Logger = config.CreateLogger();

// ...
```

If you know how to add these settings to the appsettings file, please let me know.

By the way, I use these nuget packages below:

- AWS.Logger.SeriLog
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
- Serilog
- Serilog.Enrichers.Context
- Serilog.Extensions.Logging
- Serilog.Settings.Configuration
- Serilog.Sinks.Console
- Serilog.Sinks.File